# How to rank hashtags that were created within the last 24 hours and have the highest count? Simple Hashtag Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using a gem called **simple_hashtag** https://github.com/ralovely/simple_hashtag for rails - What I'm trying to do is create a hashtag trending list using the gem. By listing the top 15 hashtags by rank and order created within the last 24 hours. I would like to push down old hashtags that are no longer popular. (which should happen throughout the 24 hour life cycle)

```
def trending_hashtags
    @whats_trending_hashtags = SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.where('created_at > ?', 24.hours.ago).order('count(hashtags.hashtaggable_id) desc')
end
```

UPDATE:
I edited my code to match AJCodez example. What I have below so far, is causing small errors. One is ambiguity for the `SimpleHashtag::Hashtagging.where("created_at >")` part of the statement and the `group("hashtags.id").order` part of the statement. I added the **timestamp** to the **simple_hashtag_hashtaggings** table.

```
 @whats_trending_hashtags = SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.left_joins(:hashtaggings).merge(SimpleHashtag::Hashtagging.where("created_at > ?", 24.hours.ago)).group('hashtags.id').order("COUNT(*) DESC").limit(20)
```

IRB console below:

```
irb(main):022:0>>> SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.left_joins(:hashtaggings).merge(SimpleHashtag::Hashtagging.where("created_at > ?", 24.hours.ago)).group('hashtags.id').order("COUNT(*) DESC").limit(20)
 SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.left_joins(:hashtaggings).merge(Sim
<tag::Hashtag.left_joins(:hashtaggings).merge(SimpleHashtag::Hashtagging.w
<ashtaggings).merge(SimpleHashtag::Hashtagging.where("created_at > ?", 24.
<ashtag::Hashtagging.where("created_at > ?", 24.hours.ago)).group('hashtag
<"created_at > ?", 24.hours.ago)).group('hashtags.id').order("COUNT(*) DES
<.ago)).group('hashtags.id').order("COUNT(*) DESC").limit(20)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as
raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "COUNT(*) DESC". Non-attribute a
rguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. This method should not be called with
user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe
 values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql(). (called from irb_binding a
t (irb):22)
  SimpleHashtag::Hashtag Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "simple_hashtag_hashtags".* FROM
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "c
"simple_hashtag_hashtags" LEFT OUTER JOIN "simple_hashtag_hashtaggings" ON "simp
le_hashtag_hashtaggings"."hashtag_id" = "simple_hashtag_hashtags"."id" WHERE (cr
reated_at" is ambiguous
eated_at > '2018-10-11 21:57:11.204021') GROUP BY hashtags.id ORDER BY COUNT(*)
DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
LINE 1: ...shtag_id" = "simple_hashtag_hashtags"."id" WHERE (created_at...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "simple_hashtag_hashtags".* FROM "simple_hashtag_hashtags" LEFT OUTER
```

UPDATE 2:
I changed the statement to the one below. I receive the error still for ambiguity, but it returns an empty array. Which means its working correctly, I guess.

```
SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.left_joins(:hashtaggings).merge(SimpleHashtag::Hashtagging.where("simple_hashtag_hashtaggings.created_at > ?", 24.hours.ago)).group('simple_hashtag_hashtags.id').order("COUNT(*) DESC").limit(20)
```

Comment: Please explain your problem. Does your code work as expected, does it produce any exception?

Comment: I updated my code to reflect the changes that were made.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using the `simple_hashtag` gem. It can only work if you add a database migration to add timestamps to the `:simple_hashtag_hashtaggings` table.

---

If you look in the templates of the project you can see migrations. In the migrations it creates some new tables.

```
create_table :simple_hashtag_hashtags do |t|
  t.string :name,             :index => true
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :simple_hashtag_hashtaggings do |t|
  t.references :hashtag,      :index => true
  t.references :hashtaggable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

You can see the `:hashtags` table has timestamps and the `:hastaggings` does not have timestamps.

How the gem works is the `:simple_hashtag_hashtags` table assigns unique hashtags to a relational database ID. So `#ootd` maps to ID `5` and `#sunset` maps to `8` for example. You could say there is a 1 to 1 relationship between `:hashtags` records and possible hashtag string values.

In the `:simple_hashtag_hashtaggings` table the gem adds records to join the hashtag ID with any model using `Hashtagging` records. So posts with three hashtags would have three associated `Hashtagging` records. You could say there is a many to many relationship between `Hashtag` and `Hashtaggable` records through `Hashtaggings`.

If you want the most popular hashtags in the past 24 hours, if you had timestamps on the `:hashtaggings` table you could calculate by grouping and counting and ordering.

In the end the query looks like the following:

```
Hashtag.left_joins(:hashtaggings).merge(Hashtagging.where("created_at > ?", 24.hours.ago)).group('hashtags.id').order("COUNT(*) DESC").limit(20)
```

- Start with `Hashtag` because you want hashtags.
- `left_joins` because you want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to allow hashtags with zero associated hashtaggings in the time period. If you want to exclude zero hashtag counts use `joins` instead.
- `merge()` is used to add conditions on join table.
- `created > ?` is used to limit hashtaggings to last 24 hours.
- `group('hashtags.id').order('COUNT(*) DESC')` is used to group hashtaggings by the hashtag itself and count how many times it occurs.
- `limit(20)` is used to take the top 20 for example.

Comment: I appreciate the thoroughness of your answer. Thank you.